# Why doesn't "npm install -g web3" work for web3js?

Tags: node.js, npm, web3js

When I run `npm install web3`, then I can run the following node.js file correctly.

```
$ cat main.js 
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

const web3 = require('web3');
console.log(web3.utils.asciiToHex('I have 100!'));
```

If I run `npm install -g web3` instead, I got the following error. Does anybody know why the command with `-g` would not work?

```
$ ./main.js 
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'web3'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/linux/test/web/Node.js/module/web3/utils/main.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `npm install -g` in the wrong way. Since you're invoking `./main.js` locally, you need to have `web3` installed in a local `node_modules/` folder.

`npm install web3` should be enough, without the `-g`.

Comment: I see other modules installed globally can work. Why `web3` has to be installed in a local `node_modules/` folder?

Comment: it's because when you `require('web3')` it is implicitly looking for the corresponding library in `node_modules` folder. Which is why you have to do something like `require('./web3')` for importing what's actually in the same folder

Comment: Installing things on globally gets you to use the module in command line but it does not import the module to the local project

Comment: @user1424739 If `web3` was a cli command you would install it globally to be able to run the cli command, but you're not using it as a cli command, you're using it at as a dependency in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to install packages globally in your machine. For that you need root access in linux or in windows you have to run cmd on administrative mode.